# title.php is ignored by wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm trying to create my own woocommerce theme from scratch, but I'm struggling with the single product page. 
My single.php is like that :

```
<!-- Importation du header -->
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="page-content">
        <?php
            wp_reset_query(); // necessary to reset query
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                the_content();
            endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And I have this hook in my content-single-product.php

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
</div>
```

If I'm right, all this lines are just calling the different templates part that are in \plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product but the thing is that the title of my product is not showing, it just doesn't exist. I tried copy title.php in my theme at my_theme\woocommerce\single-product but it's not working. Note that the function.php of my theme is empty and I tried some css code to see if it wasn't just hidden but it isn't, looks like the title isn't even generated in my code.

How can I display the title of my product ?

EDIT: I tried adding the function the_title to my price.php and it does show my title ! It looks like my title.php file is just ignored whatever I'm writting inside it.

Btw title.php is simple :

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

Comment: Why are you resetting the query before trying to output data? Don't you usually do that after?. use `the_ID()` and see if the id of the post you are trying to output is correct. Also are you sure that `content-single-product.php` is being used by `single.php`

Comment: @virtualLast Yes I know it's used cause I added some inline comments and they appeir in my page. The id is also correct. What's weird is that if I add the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' ); to my price .php, it output the right title on my page.